# how to click like a video using selenium for aparat

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have started web scraping. I   am trying to  like a video  of https://www.aparat.com/v/T8gqi?playlist=1869949 using  selenium and python but there is problem in my code that could not find correct xpath to like svg button.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager("122.0.6261.95").install())
aparat = driver.get("https://www.aparat.com/v/T8gqi?playlist=1869949")
sleep(20)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="primary"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/button')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `move_to_element(button)` from your **ActionChains** statement. As you found your like button in the first step, you don't need to use the move_to_element() method.
Here is some reference link for your better understanding
[documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html), [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/action-chains-in-selenium-python/)

Comment: tnx for your help, but my problem is to find like button xpath....

Comment: you can copy xpath from chrome but in my case the xpath you gave is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

1. I would avoid XPaths with lots of levels and/or indices (e.g., `div[3]` and `div[2]`). Instead you can use a simple CSS selector, `button[aria-label='favorite']`.
2. Best practice is to not use sleeps but instead to use `WebDriverWait`s to wait for the specific status you need, e.g. `EC.visibility_of_element_located()` for visible and `EC.element_to_be_clickable()` for clickable.
3. I would suggest you update your Selenium to the newest so you can get rid of the external driver manager and instead use the one included in Selenium, Selenium Manager.

With these changes, the updated code looks like

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://www.aparat.com/v/T8gqi?playlist=1869949'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[aria-label='favorite']"))).click()
```